# Indenting Text in the select box when something is entered into the input field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have figured out that `dir="rtl"` will make the text to position on the right side; however I want that to happen conditionally when something is written in an `input` element.

I was thinking of disabling `dir="rtl"` until something is entered into the `input` element and only then enable `rtl`. However, the problem with that is the "refresh page" requirement that the change implies.

Here is the simple drop down box with the text.

```
  <Select class="textToRight" dir="rtl">
      <div class = "toRight">
      <option class="this1"> TEXT1</option>
      <option class="this2"> TEXT2</option>
      <option class="this3"> TEXT3</option>
      </div>
    </select>
    <input class ="dontChange" placeholder="dontChange"></input>
    <input class ="change" placeholder="change"></input>
```

Comment: Nowhere in your code is `dir="rtl"`. Please add the relevant code.

Comment: yes I know, but putting it there does not help the cause. As it would make the text right to left initially which is not what this problem requires.

Comment: You have a `<div>` within your `<select>` element which isn't valid HTML ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Technical_summary)), and what "*text file*" are you referring to?

Comment: "when something is written in the text file" - Do you mean when something is written in the `input` element?

Comment: Okay that was supposed to be input element. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: It's *not* valid HTML; the `<select>` element - as the linked reference states - may contain zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements. As for "*why*" that, I'm afraid, is a question for the authors of the HTML spec (which can be found here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-select-element).

Comment: saw that and changed the comment. Oh okay i see that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, yes, you can modify an attribute of one element while an event is triggered in other by attaching an event handler.

In your case you can attach it to the `focusin` and `focusout` events.

```js
var selectBox = document.querySelector(".textToRight");
var changeInput = document.querySelector(".change");

changeInput.addEventListener("focusin", function() {
  selectBox.dir = "rtl";
});
changeInput.addEventListener("focusout", function() {
  selectBox.dir = "ltr";
});
```

```html
<select class="textToRight">
  <div class="toRight">
    <option class="this1"> TEXT1</option>
    <option class="this2"> TEXT2</option>
    <option class="this3"> TEXT3</option>
  </div>
</select>
<input class="dontChange" placeholder="dontChange"></input>
<input class="change" placeholder="change"></input>
```

But as *David Thomas* has said you, to have a `div` inside a `select` is [not valid HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-select-element).

Also, I think you are misusing the [`dir`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir) attribute, which is meant to indicates the directionality of the element's text (like in English vs Arabic languages).

Comment: Thank you for this amazing answer, but this is not what i was looking for. However I have partially figured out the answer. Your code will definitely help me in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is what i figured out once I found out about the onkeyup(). But I am still having one trouble.

JS

```
  function check(){
   document.getElementById("textToRight").dir = "rtl";


<select class="textToRight">

    <option class="this1"> TEXT1</option>
    <option class="this2"> TEXT2</option>
    <option class="this3"> TEXT3</option>

</select>

<input class="dontChange" placeholder="dontChange"></input>
<input class="change" placeholder="change" onkeyup='check()'></input>
```

I dont know how to do the snippet, but by testing it, it works. However, the problem I am having now is that I cant revert it back. So can I put a condtion on the length of the text ? if == 0 do ltr .. else dir = rtl.